Load SVG code in HTML elements by class, can't select multiple elements with the same class
I'm trying to show SVG coded icons through JS in a number of HTML elements. I figured out how I can show it once, but I can't get GetElementByClassname to select multiple elements.
This is the code I currently have:
var iconPlus = document.getElementsByClassName("plus");
iconPlus.innerHTML += '<svg viewBox="0 0 28 28">
                         <polygon points="28,12.5 15.5,12.5 15.5,0 12.5,0 12.5,12.5 0,12.5 0,15.5 12.5,15.5 12.5,28 15.5,28 15.5,15.5 28,15.5 "/>
                       </svg>';

I've also tried it it QuerySelectorAll, but I can't seem to find out where I should place the forEach element of that technique.

There is no code to call GetElementsByClassname or QuerySelectorAll on your test case.

IconPlus is an array of elements. I would use querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByClassName and loop through iconPlus using forEach

What is the function of the SVG? Now that you select a specific class name, maybe it would make sense to have a CSS selector that have the SVG as a background instead of changing the DOM x number of times.

Instead of creating HTML with classnames, then waiting till DOM exist and only then run JavaScript that creates SVG icons...
Take the modern native JavaScript route, supported in all modern browsers.

Create your own <svg-icon> Web Component
when defined

Existing <svg-icon> (HTMLUnknowElement) in your page will automagically upgrade
(something no framework can do without additional script)
New <svg-icon> will be created immediatly





<svg-icon is="add"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="remove"></svg-icon>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-icon", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let is = this.getAttribute("is");
      let dpath = {
        add:    `M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z`,
        remove: `M19 13H5v-2h14v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z`,
      }[is];
      this.innerHTML = `<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">` +
                       `<path d="${dpath}" fill="none"/></svg>`;
    }
  });
</script>

<svg-icon is="add"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="remove"></svg-icon>




Instead of changing the DOM you can use the SVG as a CSS background image.
SVG:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
  <polygon points="28,12.5 15.5,12.5 15.5,0 12.5,0 12.5,12.5 0,12.5 0,15.5 12.5,15.5 12.5,28 15.5,28 15.5,15.5 28,15.5 "/>
</svg>



.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.plus {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyOCAyOCI+CiAgPHBvbHlnb24gcG9pbnRzPSIyOCwxMi41IDE1LjUsMTIuNSAxNS41LDAgMTIuNSwwIDEyLjUsMTIuNSAwLDEyLjUgMCwxNS41IDEyLjUsMTUuNSAxMi41LDI4IDE1LjUsMjggMTUuNSwxNS41IDI4LDE1LjUgIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<div class="icon plus"></div>
<div><span class="icon plus"></span></div>



With the same SVG image, if you need to be able to control the color of it, you can use the SVG as a mask-image instead of a background image:


.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.plus {
  mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyOCAyOCI+CiAgPHBvbHlnb24gZmlsbD0iY3VycmVudGNvbG9yIiBwb2ludHM9IjI4LDEyLjUgMTUuNSwxMi41IDE1LjUsMCAxMi41LDAgMTIuNSwxMi41IDAsMTIuNSAwLDE1LjUgMTIuNSwxNS41IDEyLjUsMjggMTUuNSwyOCAxNS41LDE1LjUgMjgsMTUuNSAiLz4KPC9zdmc+');
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
<div class="icon plus red"></div>
<div><span class="icon plus green"></span></div>



